# Deliver P3P http headers for IE-8

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, p3p

we built a webapp. On IE we need to allow third party cookies. We are using Java Server Faces. Anyway we are looking for the best way to deliver the P3P-Header? We thought about Apache configuration files. Is it possible to detect InternetExplorer on this level or is it better to check for browser in the application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually do it like this: `response.addHeader("P3P", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");` Indiscriminately of the client browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it should be a static P3P policy, the elegant way would be to put it in the Apache config with

```
BrowserMatch . . 
Header . . .  env=
```

Comment: Great akberc, I found this link, which describes the command. Unfortunately I did not configure Apache-Tomcat-Environment up to now. I am using Eclipse and XAMPP on a Windows machine - in which file I have to put in the directive?

Comment: Forgot to add the link: http://attaboy.tumblr.com/post/227153662/on-internet-explorer-7-cookies-iframes-and-privacy

Comment: `\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works for me (at the end of Apache http.conf, set-header-module is enabled):

```
BrowserMatch MSIE IS_MSIE
Header add P3P "CP=\"NOI DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND OTC\"" env=IS_MSIE
```